# Hard Disk info required, attached to IBM System x3650 M4

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2012, hardware-raid

I need to get the details of a hard disk attached to an IBM System x3650 M4 server machine.

One thing I did is to search for model number shown on Device Manager under Disk Drives, but this search shows Controllers rather than Disks. I am sure I am missing something.

Could anyone help me to find a command or procedure to inspect hard disk details (model no., RPM, read/write speed, etc.)?

Name of the HD shown by `HD Tune Pro` is `IBM     ServeRAID M5110e`.

Comment: Is this on a corporate network?

Answer (score 1):

[Hard Disk Sentinel](http://www.hdsentinel.com/) helped me out in finding RPM, Model No., Serial No., and a lot of more things like temperature, SCSI properties supported, average read & write speed, data read & written so far etc